# Processing batched events with RX Observables in Hosted Service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, observable, system.reactive

I have the following scenario:

```cs
public class MyHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IEventSource _eventSource;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private IDisposable? _subscription;

    public MyHostedService(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IEventSource eventSource,
        ILogger<MyHostedService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _eventSource = eventSource;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _subscription = _eventSource.CreateEventsObservable()
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 100)
            .Where(batch => batch.Count is not 0)
            .Select((pes, batchNumber) => Observable.FromAsync(() => ProcessBatch(batchNumber, pes, stoppingToken)))
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe(
                onNext: (u) => { },
                onError: (e) => _logger.LogSubscriptionFailure(e),
                onCompleted: () => _logger.LogCompletedSubscription()
            );
    }

    private async Task ProcessBatch(
        int batchNumber, 
        IList<MyEvent> events,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var processor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IProcessor>();
            await processor.Process(events, cancellationToken);

            _logger.LogProcessedBatch(batchNumber, events.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception e) when (e is not OperationCanceledException)
        {
            _logger.LogBatchError(e, batchNumber, events.Count);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription?.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

There are a few things that bother me:

1. I noticed that the processing is a bit slow - even though the source observable (`_eventSource`) produces lots of events, the batches don't come in too fast. I wonder if I could improve the throughput here. Maybe `ProcessBatch` should use `Task.Run` internally to run the processor?
2. There are lots of events. Since `IProcessor` has some transient dependencies (like types http clients), I think I shouldn't just inject `IProcessor` and use that instance for the whole lifetime of the app. Instead I'm creating a scope everytime a batch is being processed. Is it OK for performance? Could it be better?

Comment: How often the batch is created? Or how many batches you process per minute/hour? If the problem is performance, then I'll need you to define current speed and what would be a desired level. Can you describe in general what the processor does? How long on average a single processor execution takes?

Comment: There are thousands of events per second, certainly more than this app can handle (hence I am running a few replicas of it). For every batch, there is a bunch of data that needs to be fetched from external APIs. This data is glued together into documents batch that is then inserted into MongoDB. Handling of a single batch takes ~ 100ms-500ms since there are a few network requests involved.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to have a full Rx solution. Calling `Subscribe` in your `ExecuteAsync` is not the best way to go.

You can await an observable, you know.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) =>
    await
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => _serviceProvider.CreateScope(),
                scope =>
                    from es in _eventSource.CreateEventsObservable().Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 100)
                    where es.Count > 0
                    let processor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IProcessor>()
                    from r in Observable.FromAsync(ct => processor.Process(es, ct))
                    select r)
            .Do(u => { }, (e) => _logger.LogSubscriptionFailure(e), () => _logger.LogCompletedSubscription())
            .LastAsync()
            .TakeUntil(stoppingToken.ToObservable());
```

That's close. Not quite your original query, but it should do the same processing and it's only creating one scope.

ou need this extension method:

```
public static class ObservableEx2
{
    public static IObservable<Unit> ToObservable(this CancellationToken ct) =>
        Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => ct.Register(() =>
        {
            observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            observer.OnCompleted();
        }));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why it is better? Is it going to create `IProcessor` for every batch, or just one `IProcessor` for the whole lifetime of the app?

Comment: @mnj - It's calling `.GetRequiredService<IProcessor>()` for each batch, but that's only because I wanted it inside the observable with the `let` keyword. I could have put in a block of code and created it outside of the observable (but still inside of the `Using` to truly make it only once.